# How can I use multiple filters on a single sink with boost::log

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log, boost-phoenix

I'm using a sink to log information and a file with information on the different levels I want for each tag I created like so:

```
sink->set_filter(logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::warning && expr::attr<std::string>("Tag") == tag);
[...]
sink->set_filter(logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::warning && expr::attr<std::string>("Tag") == tag1);
```

with both tag and tag1 different tags

I also tried to apply the documentation of boost::phoenix to my problem but I can't figure out how to implement it.

Right now, I have this code, but it just overrides the filter each time I get into a leaf.

```
void setSinks()
{
    logging::core::get()->add_global_attribute("Tag", attrs::mutable_constant<std::string>(""));

    std::string path = "..../log_config.json";
    
    [def of sink...]
    
    pt::ptree root;
    pt::read_json(path, root);

    std::function<void(pt::ptree, std::string)> parse_tree;

        auto setFilter = [](std::string tag, std::string logLevel) {
        logging::trivial::severity_level level;
        if (logLevel == "TRACE") level = logging::trivial::trace;
        else if (logLevel == "DEBUG") level = logging::trivial::debug;
        else if (logLevel == "INFO") level = logging::trivial::info;
        else if (logLevel == "WARNING") level = logging::trivial::warning;
        else if (logLevel == "ERROR") level = logging::trivial::error;
        else if (logLevel == "FATAL") level = logging::trivial::fatal;
        else level = logging::trivial::debug;

        return logging::trivial::severity >= level && expr::attr<std::string>("Tag") == tag;

    };

    parse_tree = [&sink, &setFilter, &parse_tree](pt::ptree tree, std::string tag)
    {
        for (const auto& v : tree)
        {
            std::string name = v.first;
            pt::ptree value = v.second;
            if (value.empty())
            {
                sink->set_filter(setFilter(tag + "." + name, value.data()));
            }
            else
            {
                parse_tree(value, (tag.empty() ? name : tag + "." + name));
            }
        }
    };

    parse_tree(root, "");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list of tags is known and fixed at compile time, you can compose a filter using template expressions like this:

```
sink->set_filter
(
    (expr::attr<std::string>("Tag") == tag1 && logging::trivial::severity >= severity1) ||
    (expr::attr<std::string>("Tag") == tag2 && logging::trivial::severity >= severity2) ||
    ...
);
```

Here, `tag1`, `tag2`, `severity1` and `severity2` may be constants or dynamic values, e.g. obtained from a file.

If the list of tags is more dynamic, you could use [`channel_severity_filter`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/expressions.html#log.detailed.expressions.predicates.channel_severity_filter). It is used to map severity level thresholds to different channels, and in your case your "Tag" attribute plays the role of a channel name.

```
// Create a threshold table. If not using keywords, you have to explicitly
// specify the value types of Tag and Severity attributes.
auto min_severity = expr::channel_severity_filter<
    std::string, logging::trivial::severity_level>("Tag", "Severity");

// Populate the table. You may do this dynamically, in a loop.
min_severity[tag] = severity;

sink->set_filter(min_severity);
```

You may also combine this filter with other template expressions, as shown in the docs.

Lastly, you can implement whatever filtering logic you want by writing your own filtering function.

```
typedef std::map<std::string, logging::trivial::severity_level> severity_table_t;

bool my_filter(
    severity_table_t const& table,
    logging::value_ref<std::string> tag,
    logging::value_ref<logging::trivial::severity_level> severity)
{
    // Check if Tag and Severity attributes were present in the log record
    if (!tag || !severity)
        return false;

    // Check if the Tag is present in the table
    auto it = table.find(*tag);
    if (it == table.end())
        return false;

    // Check if Severity satisfies the threshold
    return *severity >= it->second;
}

// Populate the table, e.g. from a file
severity_table_t table;

sink->set_filter(boost::phoenix::bind(
    &my_filter,
    table,
    expr::attr<std::string>("Tag").or_none(),
    expr::attr<logging::trivial::severity_level>("Severity").or_none()));
```

You can also do away with Boost.Phoenix and implement attribute value extraction yourself.

```
typedef std::map<std::string, logging::trivial::severity_level> severity_table_t;

// Populate the table, e.g. from a file
severity_table_t table;

sink->set_filter
(
    [table](logging::attribute_value_set const& record)
    {
        // Check if Tag and Severity attributes were present in the log record
        auto tag = record["Tag"].extract<std::string>();
        if (!tag)
            return false;

        // You can use keywords to reference attribute values
        auto severity = record[logging::trivial::severity];
        if (!severity)
            return false;

        // Check if the Tag is present in the table
        auto it = table.find(*tag);
        if (it == table.end())
            return false;

        // Check if Severity satisfies the threshold
        return *severity >= it->second;
    }
);
```